# Converting month to quarter in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my data frame denoting month (in the form `yyyy-mm`). I want to convert that to quarter using `pd.Period`.
I tried using apply function in below form but it's running too slow. Is there a better way to do this?
I am using :

```
hp2['Qtr'] = hp2.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x['Mth'],'Q'),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 11):

I would use [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method in a "vectorized" manner:

```
In [76]: x
Out[76]:
     Month
0  2016-11
1  2011-01
2  2015-07
3  2012-09

In [77]: x['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(x.Month).dt.quarter

In [78]: x
Out[78]:
     Month  Qtr
0  2016-11    4
1  2011-01    1
2  2015-07    3
3  2012-09    3
```

Or if you want to have it in `2016Q4` format (as [@root mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368677/converting-month-to-quarter-in-python-dataframe/40368766?noredirect=1#comment67991450_40368766)), using `PeriodIndex()`:

```
In [114]: x['Qtr'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(x.Mth), freq='Q')

In [115]: x
Out[115]:
       Mth    Qtr
0  2016-11 2016Q4
1  2011-01 2011Q1
2  2015-07 2015Q3
3  2012-09 2012Q3
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but the output is different than what the code in the question has, e.g. `4` vs `2016Q4`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't need the whole row, is it faster if you map the values from the column alone?

```
hp2['Qtr'] = hp2['Mth'].map(lambda x: pd.Period(x,'Q'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as @MaxU but using `astype`:

```
hp2['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(hp2['Mth'].values, format='%Y-%m').astype('period[Q]')
```

The resulting output:

```
        Mth    Qtr
0   2014-01 2014Q1
1   2017-02 2017Q1
2   2016-03 2016Q1
3   2017-04 2017Q2
4   2016-05 2016Q2
5   2016-06 2016Q2
6   2017-07 2017Q3
7   2016-08 2016Q3
8   2017-09 2017Q3
9   2015-10 2015Q4
10  2017-11 2017Q4
11  2015-12 2015Q4
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a large sample dataset:

```
n = 10**5
yrs = np.random.choice(range(2010, 2021), n)
mths = np.random.choice(range(1, 13), n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mth': ['{0}-{1:02d}'.format(*p) for p in zip(yrs, mths)]})
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Mth'].values, format='%Y-%m').astype('period[Q]')
10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop

%timeit pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.Mth), freq='Q')
1 loop, best of 3: 2.68 s per loop

%timeit df['Mth'].map(lambda x: pd.Period(x,'Q'))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.26 s per loop

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x['Mth'],'Q'),axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.49 s per loop
```

Comment: This is interesting: `pd.to_datetime(x['Mth'].values).astype('period[Q]')` works, but `pd.to_datetime(x['Mth']).astype('period[Q]')` gives `TypeError: data type "period[Q]" not understood` - is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @MaxU: I noticed the same thing, and I think it's because of what `pd.to_datetime` returns.  When you pass a Series, you get back a Series, but when you pass a list/array, it will return a DatetimeIndex.  From what I've read in the documentation, `period[Q]` will only work with a DatetimeIndex.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to be working on a df that contains 9994 rows so I tested your code against what I've used in the past and posted the results for you.
Here is a sample of the df, not exactly YYYY-MM but it doesn't matter because the code will work on either:

```
hp2['Mth'][:10]
Out[11]: 
0   2016-06-26
1   2016-06-26
2   2016-06-26
3   2016-06-26
4   2016-06-26
5   2016-06-26
6   2016-06-26
7   2016-06-26
8   2016-06-26
9   2016-06-26
Name: Mth, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I ran your code on my df:

```
%timeit hp2['Qtr_Period']= hp2.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x['Mth'],'Q'), axis=1)
hp2['Qtr_Period'][:10]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.28 s per loop
Out[13]: 
0   2016Q2
1   2016Q2
2   2016Q2
3   2016Q2
4   2016Q2
5   2016Q2
6   2016Q2
7   2016Q2
8   2016Q2
9   2016Q2
Name: Qtr_Period, dtype: object
```

Then I tested it using this:

```
%timeit hp2['Qtr_dt']= (df['Order Date'].dt.year.astype(str))+'Q'+(df['Order Date'].dt.quarter.astype(str))
hp2['Qtr_dt'][:10]
10 loops, best of 3: 67.6 ms per loop
Out[14]: 
0    2016Q2
1    2016Q2
2    2016Q2
3    2016Q2
4    2016Q2
5    2016Q2
6    2016Q2
7    2016Q2
8    2016Q2
9    2016Q2
Name: Qtr_dt, dtype: object
```

It is clear from the results. Hope that helps. You can find more information on [pandas.Series.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
month = ['2016-11', '2011-01', '2015-06', '2012-09']
x = pd.DataFrame(month, columns=["month"])
x.month = pd.to_datetime(x.month)
x['quarter'] = [pd.Period(x.month[i], freq='M').quarter for i in range(len(x))]
x

    month     quarter
0   2016-11-01  4
1   2011-01-01  1
2   2015-06-01  2
3   2012-09-01  3
```